# Function limit derivation using asymptotic analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I have a limit derivation in my book, and several steps that I can't understand.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}x^2(\sqrt[7]{\frac{x^3+x}{1+x^3}} - cos(\frac{1}{x}))$$

(1) $\frac{x^3+x}{1+x^3} = 1 + \frac{1}{x^2} + O(\frac{1}{x^3})$

Formula which is used here is

$$(1+x)^a = 1 + \frac{a}{1!}x+...+ (\frac{a*(a-1)*...(a-n+1)}{n!}x^n + O(x^{n+1})$$

However, I don't quite get this step

(2) $(1+\frac{1}{x^2})(1-\frac{1}{x^3}+O(\frac{1}{x^6})) = 1 + \frac{1}{x^2} + O(\frac{1}{x^3})$

Simple brackets opening doesn't seem to work, and I don't know any $O(.)$ properties to get this result.

(3) Next, if $cos(1/x)=1-\frac{1}{2x^2}+O(\frac{1}{x^4})$

How we derive

(4) $\sqrt[7]{\frac{x^3+x}{1+x^3}} - cos(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{9}{14x^2}+O(\frac{1}{x^3})$

Specifically, where $O(\frac{1}{x^4})$ has gone?

And finally, is final answer is 9/14, does that means that we can say

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}O(1/x)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

For $(2)$, Expanding the bracket immediately gives:
\begin{align*}(1+\frac{1}{x^2})(1-\frac{1}{x^3}+O(\frac{1}{x^6})) &=1-\frac{1}{x^3}+O(\frac{1}{x^6})+ \frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^5}+O(\frac{1}{x^8}) \\&= 1 + \frac{1}{x^2}-\color{red}{\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^5} + O(\frac{1}{x^6})}\\&= 1 + \frac{1}{x^2}+\color{red}{O(\frac{1}{x^3})}.\end{align*}
And similarly for your second question: the $\frac{1}{x^4}$ is absorbed by the $O(\frac{1}{x^2}).$

The property you need are :

- $g=O(g)$
- If $g=O(f)$ then $g+O(f)=O(f)$.
- If $g=O(f)$ then $f+O(g)=O(f)$.
- If $g=O(f)$ then $O(f)+O(g)=O(f)$.

Comment: I can't understand why $O(\frac{1}{x^6}) - \frac{1}{x^3} -  \frac{1}{x^5} = O(\frac{1}{x^3})$